# kendo-ui combobox applied to multiple inputs

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-combobox

I am using a jquery selector to grab a group of inputs and make them into kendoComboBoxes which works fine. My problem is when hitting the remote datasource I do not know how to set the **filterstring** to the data the user typed.  $(this) doesn't seem to work.

```
$("input[name$='].RCNumber']").kendoComboBox({
            placeholder: "Enter UserID or Name",
            dataTextField: "EmpUserID",
            minLUserth: 3,
            dataValueField: "EmpUserID",
            //change: onUserSelect,
            template: "<table cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'><tr><td style='width:100px;'>${data.EmpUserID}</td>" +
                          "<td style='width:150px;'>${data.Name}</td>" +
                          "<td style='width:300px;'>${data.Title}</td>" +
                          "<td style='width:250px;'>${data.Department}</td></tr></table>",

            filter: "contains",
            autoBind: false,
            dataSource: {
                serverFiltering: true,
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: "json",
                        url: "/Home/GetUsers/",
                            data: {
                                filterString: function () {
                                    var tmp = $(this).data("kendoComboBox").text(); return tmp;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }).data("kendoComboBox");
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  Just replace this...

```
var tmp = $(this).data("kendoComboBox").text(); return tmp;
```

...with this...

```
var tmp = $(document.activeElement).val(); return tmp;
```

Because the dropdown you are working with has focus at the time the data method is called.